# Chrome Desktop Notification bigger size

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently using chrome desktop notifications but at my job they want a larger desktop notifications and chrome notifications has size limits.  Is there anyway i can overcome this restriction?  Are there any alternative methods i can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't overcome this easily.

Both notification APIs, `chrome.notifications` and Web [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification), do not allow you to specify the geometry of the notification.

Alternative methods? Sure, everything is possible, but is going to be painful and/or ugly.

You could try showing popup windows with `chrome.windows` (as that allows you to set geometry), or you could try to add a native host that shows notifications for you using [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). Both solutions are bad, of course.

Comment: why are these solutions bad?

Comment: A popup window won't normally stay on top, and will look like a browser window and not a notification. You'll also have to manually compute geometry/position for it. A native host can display literally anything, but it complicates extension install (it cannot be bundled together with the extension, you need a separate installer).